# How to show only week and time in DatePickerView?

Tags: iphone, alarm, xcode4.4

In my application, i want to raise the notification using selected day and time, not with date.So i have to show the day and time only in DatePickerView. Would you please help me in this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this purpose.

For example:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// e.g. "Tue 16:53"
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE HH:mm"];

NSString *szDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
[dateFormatter release];
NSLog(@"Date formatted: %@", szDate);
```

(remove release if ARC is enabled);

And btw, the questions of this kind were asked [million](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nsdateformatter%20nsdate) times around stackoverflow